# Neo4Js client error apoc.load.csv failed procedure. caused by ArrayIndexOutofBoundException 1

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am newbie to NEO4J. I am using neo4j version 3.5.6 community edition and apoc plugins version 3.5.0.4 .I have a CSV file in default import folder

NR_Nodes_Agent_I_20190331_tmp.csv. For testing purpose   I have written a cypher query

```
 CALL apoc.load.csv('NR_Nodes_Agent_I_20190331_tmp.csv') yield map as row return row;
```

but I am getting bellow error

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.csv`: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

I did some research on it but haven't successful  to solve
I uncommented statement  in neo4j.conf file

```
dbms.directories.import=import 
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,apoc.*
```

Comment: Are you able to provide the callstack for that exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have this setting in your `neo4j.conf` file:

   ```
   apoc.import.file.enabled=true
   ```
2. Make sure your CSV file is well-formed.

   - For example, this CSV file would cause the same `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` error message (notice that the single data row is missing a second value, since it has one fewer comma than the header):

     ```
     a,b
     1
     ```
   - On the other hand, this CSV file would work, even though the data row has no value after the comma):

     ```
     a,b
     1,
     ```

     The query result would be:

     ```
     ╒════════════════╕
     │"row"           │
     ╞════════════════╡
     │{"a":"1","b":""}│
     └────────────────┘
     ```
   - And if the data row had a second value, like this:

     ```
     a,b
     1,2
     ```

     Then the query result would be:

     ```
     ╒═════════════════╕
     │"row"            │
     ╞═════════════════╡
     │{"a":"1","b":"2"}│
     └─────────────────┘
     ```