# What causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when importing csv in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I  want to import a csv table with tweets from twitter. But I get the error message:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.csv`: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4

My Code is:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv("conversations_until_2021_06_18.tsv", {
  sep: "TAB",
  arraySep: ",",
  skip: 100000,
  mapping: {
    hashtags: {array: true},
    mentions: {array: true},
    ref_id: {array: true},
    reply_count: {type: "int"},
    retweet_count: {type: "int"},
    quote_count: {type: "int"},
    like_count: {type: "int"}
    }
  }
)
YIELD map AS tweet
CREATE (t:Tweet)
SET t = tweet
```

Please provide the following information if you ran into a more serious issue:

I'm using Neo4j v4.3.1, Desktop v1.4.5

An example:

```
comment_type    conversatoin_id text    author_id   tweet_id    ref_type    ref_id  in_reply_to_user_id created_at  mentions    url hashtags    like_count  quote_count reply_count retweet_count   reply_settings
side    1234  @url https://t.co/...   345  5678  replied_to 564465   4566   2021-04-28T15:55:42.000Z    ABaerbock, ArminLaschet https://twitter.com/...     NaN 0   0   0   0   everyone
```

One of my files works fine, but the second produces this error. According to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563157/neo4js-client-error-apoc-load-csv-failed-procedure-caused-by-arrayindexoutofbou) question there my be a problem with a line in the file. But how to find that line? I have no idea where an array of length 4 could be.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to upload a huge document. Unfortunately, this exception does not provide you with supplemental information; it just flags a formatting issue of the file.

I used the "," separator and it continuously failed. As a result, I analyzed the data and decided to use a different separator; for example, none of my fields contained the character ">", so I have used it as a separator and avoided the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had some strings with backslashes (which escaped the following tab). Deleting them solved it for me.